# D3.js nest function, cannot get data into hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

So I am trying to create d3.js tree. My data must be in the hierarchical form before it can be passed to d3.treeLayout.

at this moment here how my json array looks like

```
var data = [
      {"group":"1","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"2","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"3","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"4","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"1","price":"1241.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"2","price":"36595429.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"3","price":"12124.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"group":"4","price":"6264.88", "cy":"44260"},
    ]
```

And I use d3.nest() function that must group the entries

```
var NestedBudget = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d){
                        return d.group;
                    })
                    .entries(data);
```

However, this data is not working when i further pass it to d3.hierarchy(). [image]

I attached the picture of the outcome I receive after I pass it to `var root_data = d3.hierarchy(data);`

I hope I didn't confuse anyone. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you want to have a **tree**. A tree needs to have a root element and every node needs 2 things : an unique id, and a field which links to his parent's id.

For instance, with the data that you have, by adding an id field and assuming that "group" represent the parent node, you can transform your flat data into a hierarchical one :

```js
var data = [
      {"id":"0", "group":null, "price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"1", "group":"0", "price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"2", "group":"0","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"3", "group":"0","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"4", "group":"0","price":"36599.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"5", "group":"1","price":"1241.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"6", "group":"2","price":"36595429.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"7", "group":"3","price":"12124.88", "cy":"44260"},
      {"id":"8", "group":"4","price":"6264.88", "cy":"44260"},
    ];
    
const tree = d3
      .stratify()
      .id(d => d.id)
      .parentId(d => d.group)(data);
      
console.log(tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the node with the `"group":null` is the root node (by definition a root node is the starting node of your tree, so it doesn't have any parent).

Comment: Awesome! I see now why it didn't work. I have one more question since I am getting my data from the from back-end rest framework, there is no way I would be able to change the group to null, does d3 offers something that could assign the root node?

Comment: Good question. The `"group":null` is not mandotary, I wrote it in order to make it more understandable. If you don't add the `group` key, the stratify method won't be able to find a parent for this node, which is perfectly fine since it is the root node. So you can omit the group key for the root node. Please tick the thread as resolved it the answer satisfied your need :)

Comment: Well, my question is how can I add parent root? Do you know any reference I could read?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see. Why don't you just edit your data to add a root node yourself ? something like `data = [{"id":"0", "group":null}, ...data];` just before defining the `const tree =...` variable ?

Comment: I would, but data changes every time. I am using AJAX and receiving my data from back-end REST. So the data will change everytime

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what Pierre Capo said was right. I added var `packableData = {id:"parent", values:data};`

to the data I am receiving and that will set the parent in the hierarchy when you pass it to d3.hierarchy()